Некорректная работа SIM800L
Ситуация следующая: У меня в наличии Orange Pi 3 lts, SIM800L, простенький сервер на Flask с белым статическим IP и система Armbian. Все манипуляции делаются на питоне.
Что пытаюсь сделать - Подключив sim800l по UART  к оранжу, мне нужно по определенному тригеру в коде переправлять пакет данных в формате json по GPRS. Програмный код написан на языке python. Пытаюсь использовать библиотеку PySerial и библиотеку по этой ссылке https://pypi.org/project/sim800l-gsm-module/.
Что не работает - во время тестового прогона подключения к серверу(т.е. когда я руками вбиваю команды через терминал, использую для этого модуль atcom) связь с сервером устанавливается, но т.к. atcom поддержичает исключительно передачу AT команд, то я не могу уложить через него json, и делаю это через echo -e 'Данные' > /dev/ttyS3. На сервере возвращается 400  ошибка. Когда я настроил все через библиотеку по ссылке, в меня начало выдавать критические ощибки, т.к. на команду  'AT+SAPBR=x,1', модуль возвращает нечитаемый ответ. Уточню, что ответ нечитаем всегда, когда приходит на x=1,0, всегда читаем при x=2, и не всегда читаем при x = 3.
Если у кого есть опыт в устранении этого недоразумения, поделитесь пожалуйста!!
